# Batch exporting of Android APKs

Tags: android, eclipse

Let's say I have a whole lot of Android projects, how would I go about, export and digitally sign them all at once, is it even possible to do through eclipse?

Any thoughts of the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Eclipse it's not possible to export multiple projects without human intervention.

You can script it by creating ANT build.xml files for all of your projects. The ANT build files allow you to specify the keystore path and key alias that you want to use to sign your APK.

You can create a simple script that goes through all of your projects, and calls the ant release target. This will generate a signed APK file.

That way, you can export all of your apps with a single script.

More information can be found on :
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: hi @ddewaele, would you please help me about this, thanks a lot!>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714857/export-multiple-apk-for-different-market-using-ant