# Error with self-bootstrapping Ant build

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, ant, ant-contrib

I'm trying to write an Ant build that does *not* require me adding Ant-plugins to Ant's lib directory, or `/home/myuser/.ant/lib`, or in my Eclipse instance's ant home, etc; namely because I will eventually be building my project on a hosted Jenkins server where I do not have access to the system's Ant installation.

I'm calling this a "self-bootstrapping" build, because I use Ivy to pull down my Ant plugins at build time, and hopefully, with some proper configuration, make their tasks available to Ant dynamically.

The jist of my build (using [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) plugin as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="myapp" default="audit" basedir="."
        xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant"
        xmlns:antcontrib="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib">

    <!-- Build path. -->
    <path id="build.path">
        <fileset dir="${lib.buildtime.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="bootstrap">
        <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml"
            uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="build.path"/>
    </target>

    <target name="resolve" depends="bootstrap">
        <ivy:settings url="${ivy.settings.home}"/>

        <ivy:cleancache/>

        <ivy:resolve file="${ivy.xml}"/>

        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${gen.lib.main.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" conf="main"/>
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${gen.lib.test.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" conf="test"/>
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${gen.lib.buildtime.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]" conf="buildtime"/>

        <ivy:report todir="${gen.staging.dir}" />

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path" conf="buildtime"/>
    </target>

    <target name="taskdefs" depends="resolve">
        <taskdef resource="/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"
            uri="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" classpathref="build.path"/>

        <property name="fizz" value="buzz" />

        <antcontrib:if>
            <antcontrib:equals arg1="${fizz}" arg2="buzz" />
            <antcontrib:then>
                <echo message="Fizz is buzz!" />
            </antcontrib:then>
            <antcontrib:else>
                <echo message="Fizz is not buzz!" />
            </antcontrib:else>
        </antcontrib:if>
    </target>
</project>
```

When I run the `taskdefs` target, instead of seeing an echoed "*Fizz is buzz!*" message in my Ant output, I get the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/myuser/eclipse/workspace/myapp/build.xml:169: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:net.sf.antcontrib:if
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration. 
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
    -/home/myuser/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/lib
    -/home/myuser/.ant/lib
    -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
```

Is what I am trying to do (avoid having to do 1 of the 3 recommended things above) impossible? If so, why? If not, what is wrong with my setup here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally create a single "boostrap" target and use this to install ivy into the "$HOME/.ant/lib" directory. See:

- [Ivy fails to resolve a dependency, unable to find cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853851/ivy-fails-to-resolve-a-dependancy-unable-to-find-cause/9855381#9855381)

The following is a more complete example that does what you're trying to do:

- [How to include ant-contrib.jar dynamically in Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891893/how-to-include-ant-contrib-jar-dynamically-in-ant/12900768#12900768)

In conclusion, it's a shame ivy is not packaged by default with ANT. If you discover your hosted service prevents you from copying files into the home directory, then perhaps the simplest thing to do is ship a copy of the ivy jar alongside your source (and enable it using a taskdef)

## Update

Use the following taskdef for ant-contrib:

```
<taskdef uri="antlib:net.sf.antcontrib" classpathref="build.path"/>
```

The [homepage](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) needs update. At some stage in the recent past the library was repackaged as an [antlib](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/antlib.html).

Comment: Thanks a million @Mark O'Connor (+1) - so I read both links over very carefully and *believe* I'm doing everything the 2nd link is recommending, and still getting the exact same build error. I have updated my original post to contain all my build targets up to the one that is causing the error. **Can you spot where I'm going awrye??** Thanks again!