# How to abstract ant-contrib cross-platform?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ant, homebrew, ant-contrib

Is there a preferred method for calling ant-contrib from your build scripts in such a way that platform differences won't get in the way?

I originally prepared my build from Ubuntu, but when running on OSX with ant-contrib installed via Homebrew, I end up with errors.  Seemingly because the contrib jar can't be found.

Comment: For people using Homebrew, please be sure to look at this github issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/41469

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891893/how-to-include-ant-contrib-jar-dynamically-in-ant/12900768#12900768

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way to install Ant-Contrib is mentioned in [this page](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/#install):

1. Either install it under the `lib` folder of the Ant installation, and just import it using:

   ```
   <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>
   ```
2. Save the Jar file in a known location, perhaps relative to the buildfile, and specify its path:

   ```
   <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="path_to_ant_contrib_jar"/>
     </classpath>
   </taskdef>
   ```