# Ant - how to print file name from fileset in a filterchain

Tags: ant

I want to prepend each matching line with file name where it's found.

I tried `${file.name}`, but it does not work.

```
<concat destFile="report.xml">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontainsregexp>
            <regexp pattern="somePattern"/>
        </linecontainsregexp>
        <prefixlines prefix="${file.name}"/>
    </filterchain>
    <fileset dir="${pathToDirectory}" erroronmissingdir="false">
        <include name="**"/>
    </fileset>
</concat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses the [`<for>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) from the third-party [Ant-Contrib library](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). `<for>` iterates over every file in a fileset.

```xml
<for param="file.path">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="${pathToDirectory}" erroronmissingdir="false">
      <include name="**"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
  <sequential>
    <concat destFile="report.xml" append="true">
      <path>
        <pathelement location="@{file.path}"/>
      </path>
      <filterchain>
        <linecontainsregexp>
          <regexp pattern="somePattern"/>
        </linecontainsregexp>
        <prefixlines prefix="@{file.path}:"/>
      </filterchain>
    </concat>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

To use Ant-Contrib, download [ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip/download), extract ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar from it, and follow the instructions on [how to install Ant-Contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902480/1078068).

Comment: One thing I have to add: append="true" is mandatory with this solution, but it means that when you run build twice, the file will have duplicate output.

To avoid this, you need to add <delete file="report.xml" failonerror="true"/> before <for>