# Apache Ant - Intellij Idea Community don't recognize for loop command

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, ant-contrib

I want to create a for loop to iterate over lines of a file. 
I did:

```
<loadfile property="download.file" srcfile="download_list.txt"/>

<target name="criarArvore">
    <mkdir dir="${download.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${domain.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="download" depends="criarArvore">
    <for param="line" list="${download.file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
        <sequential>
            <echo>@{line}</echo>
        </sequential>
    </for>
</target>
```

But at `<for>` intellij warns me: 'cannot resolve symbol "for"'.
When I run the script I receive:

```
c:\xxx\build.xml:22: Problem: failed to create task or type for
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<for>` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) is from the third-party [Ant-Contrib library](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/).

To use Ant-Contrib, download [ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/1.0b3/ant-contrib-1.0b3-bin.zip/download), extract ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar from it, and follow the instructions on [how to install Ant-Contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12902480/1078068).

Comment: I cannot install ant-contrib properly. I follow the install link you pass and the official installation guide: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/ and others guides I found on internet and could not make it works.  It seems to be outdated as It is dated 2002 - 2003.

Comment: now I got it! I follow up the installation manual contained on zip file. It seems intellij don't recognize it, but the task works.